# Graph API Feed returning nothing (stopped working without change in code)

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

Guys i am having an issue with querying the Graph API for feed

I had the following query :

```
me/feed?fields=message,comments.fields(comments,likes,from,id,message,user_likes,created_time,like_count),from,link,id,to,likes.fields(id),created_time,actions,feed_targeting&limit=40
```

that was working fine till last week...

Today its not working.. tried also `me/feed/` and still it ain't working.. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your access token with the [Facebook debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to make sure it hasn't expired.
2. Check the query with the [Facebook Graph Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to confirm the query itself is sound and is returning the expected results.

Comment: for some reason, when trying from the graph explorer from my facebook profile-> /me/feed/ no data is returned... but when i tried it from my friends facebook it works perfectly ! the issue seems something to do with my facebook account..